# Are "unlabeled" graphs isomorphism classes of labeled graphs? How can people say things like $K_n$ is "the" complete graph on $n$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

For example when one says something along the lines of $K_n$  is the complete graph on $n$-vertices what exactly are they referring to? An unlabeled graph or a labeled graph?

If its labeled then don't they have to specify $E(K_n)$ and $V(K_n)$ first?

If its unlabeled then is it an isomorphism class? If not then what it is formally?

Are unlabeled graphs not isomorphism classes of labeled graphs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math is more important than the formal description of the math.

Yes, if we're defining a (simple) graph as a pair $(V,E)$, where each $e \in E$ is a subset of $V$ of size $2$, then there are multiple graphs that are "complete graphs on $n$ vertices". So we could let $K_n$ denote the isomorphism class of complete graphs on $n$ vertices, and sometimes we refer to such an isomorphism class as an "unlabeled graph".

But in practice, it's convenient to make statements like "The complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\binom n2$ edges", and pretty much everyone does it when the vertex set is irrelevant, which is almost always. It would be more technically correct to say "*Every* complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\binom n2$ edges", but this statement is a bit confusing. It reminds us of the statement "Every tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges", but unlike the statement about trees, the statement about complete graphs doesn't actually need to consider multiple different cases. Once you've proven that one complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\binom n2$ edges, you know that they all do.

In actual usage, it makes the most sense to interpret $K_n$ as denoting an arbitrary complete graph, whose vertex set we don't care about, because everything we say will work no matter what it is.

P.S. I'd be careful about the word "labeled graph". This, in actual usage, can be understood to mean something like "graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ for some $n$". For example:

- When we ask "How many unlabeled trees are there on $n$ vertices?" it's fair to translate that into "How many isomorphism classes of trees with $n$ vertices are there?"
- When we ask "How many labeled trees are there on $n$ vertices?" the answer is $n^{n-2}$, not $\infty$: we are asking about the number of trees on a fixed set of $n$ vertices, which doesn't need to be $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ but might as well be.

Comment: Alright, that sorta makes sense. If at some point I wanted to talk about a complete graph with a specific vertex set say $S$. Would it be okay of me to write something like $V(K_n)=S$ or would I need to define a new graph $G\cong K_n$ and say $V(G)=S$.

Comment: Thank you Misha, final question (sorry). So I'll avoid saying *label a graphs vertices with the set $S$*, would it then be okay to say something like **consider the complete graph $K_n$ with vertex set $V(K_n)=S$**

Comment: Use $K_n$ if you're only ever going to have *one* complete graph on $n$ vertices around, in which case any of your options are fine. Otherwise, say "Let $G$ be the complete graph with vertex set $S$".

Comment: I wouldn't say "a labeled graph is a graph on $\{1,...n\}$" necessarily; it's just a graph on some fixed set.  "How many labeled trees are there on $n$ vertices?" just means "How many labeled trees are there on a set of $n$ vertices?" (the particular set obviously not affecting the answer).  And then yes an unlabeled graph is an isomorphism class of labeled graphs.

Answer (score 2):

When people talk about $K_n$ they are talking about unlabeled graphs.  Unlabeled graphs are much more common than labeled graphs, and if no qualifier is given, it's all but certain that an unlabeled graph is meant.  Yes, it's (a representative of) an isomorphism class.

I don't quite understand the meaning of the last question.  Unlabeled graphs are not labeled graphs, clearly, so how could they be isomorphism classes of labeled graphs?  Also, a graph is not an isomorphism class, but a representative of such a class.

Comment: It's common to define "unlabeled graph" to mean "isomorphism class of labeled graphs", actually; Douglas West's textbook does it, for instance. The argument is that any given graph has some specific vertex set, so it is labeled because we can distinguish the vertices.

Comment: I questioned if unlabled graphs were an isomorphism class of labeled graphs, as this seems to be a prevalent technique in mathematical constructions when one wishes to refer to a general object/property/item that can be expressed in many different ways. For example equivalence classes of sequences of rational numbers to represent real numbers. Equivalence classes of integral ratio pairs to represent rational numbers.  etc. etc.

Comment: @MishaLavrov That's interesting.  My knowledge of graphs is more algorithmic than theoretic, but I have looked through some theoretical texts, and I've never seen that approach.  I must say it seems at variance with the usual usage.  Are groups automorphism classes of labeled groups?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I've seen things like $G\cong K_n$ when people mean to say $G$ is a labeled complete graph, wouldn't it be proper to write $G\in K_n$ then? Also based on your account history (lots of combinatorics/graph-theory) I'd really appreciate your opinion as it seems you're very knowledge in this area. In particular on how I should view "unlabeled" graphs in general, and the referencing of specific graphs without the specification of particular edge/vertex sets. E.g. $K_n$ complete graph, $W_n$ wheel graph, $K_{m,n}$ complete bipartite graph, $T(n,r)$ Turan graph etc etc.

Comment: @saulspatz I should have said "isomorphism class of graphs" not "isomorphism class of labeled graphs", since "labeled graph" connotes something different. There are infinitely many groups of order $4$, but only two unlabeled groups of order $4$, and if you asked me "how many labeled groups of order $4$ are there?" I would take that to mean "how many group operations can be defined on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$?" and get something like $16$.